# Solenoid circuit not firing

Tags: circuit-analysis, raspberry-pi, programming, solenoid

[image]

I will try to explain as quickly as possible. I am trying to get the solenoid to fire, it is not. The relay however is clicking on command.

I am recreating the circuit shown here https://www.instructables.com/A-Raspberry-Pi-Powered-Junk-Drum-Machine/ but with slight changes since my solenoid is not a 12V but I assume 9 volt (since it is typically charged by a 9 volt battery.)

I am forced to assume it is a powering issue or my wiring is wrong (although I do not understand how since I am posting here.) The wire I am using is typical bell wire from Home Depot. The relay I am using I believe is the same as the one in the project I linked but I believe has the same specs as the one below:

[image]

I am trying to get the solenoid to fire on command from the Raspberry Pi.

I have gotten it to work in the past with a 12volt 10 ampere battery pack but with code that executed as soon as the program started and then turned off. I changed the code and fried my previous solenoid realizing I had no idea what I was doing. But now I cannot get the solenoid to fire (even though my relay does click on command.)

The code I am calling is here:

```
const LED = new GPIO(9, 'out')


function fire(){
const blinkInterval = setInterval(blinkLED, 250);

function blinkLED() { //function to start blinking
  if (LED.readSync() === 0) { //check the pin state, if the state is 0 (or off)
    LED.writeSync(1); //set pin state to 1 (turn LED on)
  } else {
    LED.writeSync(0); //set pin state to 0 (turn LED off)
  }
}

function endBlink() { //function to stop blinking
  clearInterval(blinkInterval); // Stop blink intervals
  LED.writeSync(0); // Turn LED off
}

setTimeout(endBlink, 500); //Each 500 is a single shot
};
```

Comment: I just realized the circuit diagram I made isn't fairly accurate. The raspberry pi I KNOW is hooked up to the relay correctly so please ignore that part.

Comment: Please fix your schematic and proofread your text.  It's very unclear how you have this thing hooked up.

Comment: So, we are to assume that the circuit is right and try to find what's wrong? Anyway, the most likely culprit is that your microcontroller does not have enough juice to make the solenoid work as expected. Try to add a transistor along the path to increase the current. Like here: https://www.nutsvolts.com/magazine/article/bipolar_transistor_cookbook_part_3 (under relay drivers)

Comment: @SredniVashtar:  The solenoid isn't supposed to be powered from the Pi.  There's a separate power supply for the solenoid in the schematic.  The schematic is wrong, though.

Comment: The circuit is clear outside of the relay saying the coil goes to nowhere. I didn't see that until after I posted. The relay works as intended. I am more curious about the code and the power. For testing purposes I have hooked up the solenoid directly to the battery just to see if it worked and it does not. I am left to assume that 9 volts 1 amp is not enough unfortunately. I don't quite understand how that is possible if the solenoid I am using is typically powered by a 9 volt battery.

Comment: @J.Doe: 1.  Your schematic is wrong.  The relay cannot click if it is wired as the schematic shows.  Fix the schematic.  2.  After you fix the schematic post photos of how you built the circuit.  You seem to have wired something wrong, and we can't help you find that from just the schematic diagram.

Comment: @JRE I do not understand what NC and NO on the relay the schematic set gave me means. I just wanted to show that I was running the negative wire back to the relay to show the complete circuit with the battery pack involved.

Comment: @JRE yeah, I agree that the schematic is wrong and without a crystal ball there is no way we know what the OP has. From the instructable page it appears they are using relays with optocouplers. From the look at the relay picture here it appears the module only has a transistor onboard. It might be a missing ground connection, wrong polarity... who knows. Crystal balla are so hard to come by these days...

Comment: A relay switches the "common" between the "normally  closed" and "normally open" contacts when you energize the coil.  Your diagram should have the 9V supply connected to the common and the solenoid connected to the NC or NO terminal.

Comment: Also, your "relay" isn't just a relay.  It includes a driver circuit with a transistor.  The GPIO pins from a Pi can't normally drive a relay coil by themselves. The GPIO drives the transistor which allows current from the 5V through the relay coil.

Comment: @J.Doe The solenoid I was talking about is that of the relay. But since you have a transistor onboard, you should also post the schematic of your relay module and also at what pin you attached the actuator (which happens to be a solenoid as well). Since you hear the relay clicking, try to power a lesser load, like a small fairy light or a LED (with correct polarity). Maybe you wired the actuator wrong...

Comment: @JRE I have tried to edit the circuit diagram but the post just got worse. I don't understand how this website only allows you to upload photos once. Anyway, I have the solenoid hooked up to the NC terminal and the 9v battery supply is connected to common.

Comment: If this is the way it's wired https://i.stack.imgur.com/dSua4.jpg it's wrong. See this page https://www.electronicshub.org/use-5v-relay-arduino/ under "Circuit diagram". The block with the transistor and the relay is your module, the 5V from the pi will power that. And then attach your actuator, in series with the supply to the common and normally open (or closed - suit yourself) contacts of the relay

Comment: @SredniVashtar I have tried that without the relay involved (just getting code to work). I will try that including the relay to see if it is the relay issue but I really think it's just a power thing. Do you guys know how to read a solenoid using a multimeter? I have tried and for the life of me, I am getting no numbers. It is a small clapper solenoid.

Comment: @sredniVashtar I am trying to understand the difference in guides. I was trying to do this as simple as possible and I chose the guide in my original post because it didn't have all the different parts but still powered the solenoids. I am wondering why I would need to do that here if I too am trying to only power a solenoid?

Comment: @J.Doe I've fixed your post.  There was a mix up with the formatting from the code.  You should be able to insert your new schematic now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comments have made it clear that you don't understand the difference between a relay and a relay module, and that you don't understand what the contacts on a relay are for.

Here's a circuit that shows how your gadget should be built:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fTDbpJ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I've shown the internal circuit of the module to make clear just what is going on.

You seem to have the input side wired correctly, since you hear the relay click.

The output side is where the error lies.

If you connected your solenoid and power supply to the NC and NO contacts, then the relay would click but the solenoid would not activate.

Your module should have the NC, NO, and C terminals marked, probably on the bottom side under the blue connector.

Comment: Hello, thank you with your help. I have tried to study what you have given me and I am still failing to understand why I am failing at designing this circuit. The solenoid does activate but it's uncontrollable with my current design (the one in the given link description I sent in the original post). Once plugged in, it just constantly clicks once I run the program instead of waiting on my queue. I really am trying to understand here.

Comment: I guess what I am asking is I still don't fully comprehend in plain English why I might need to add extra steps to my circuit to get it to run while the original guide I have been using seems to only need the relay

Comment: You probably don't need extra steps.  You probably just need to do the ones you have right.  You might have forgotten to connect the ground from the Pi to the relay module.

Comment: I'll go over the circuit and rebuild it from the ground up again and try to explain clearly any issues I am having. I appreciate the continued help.

Comment: Just wanted to bring this to a close. I appreciate the help. I tried to check the relay to see for NC NO and C terminals. I couldn't find where they were but realized that since I was getting power to the solenoid and you helped me walk through the issue, I figured if I kept taking note of where I plugged it in, I would figure out which contacts are which.

The relay was setup backwards. I figured out the contacts by just plugging and playing. It works as designed now. Thank you.