# Solenoid misfire with Raspberry Pi. Circuit works?

Tags: raspberry-pi, solenoid

I have a clapper solenoid that can't seem to fully clap. I am assuming it is a power issue but I am at a loss for how so I figured I would post here in case I have missed something. This is what my circuit looks like:

[image]

[image]

The program I am running from the raspberry pi I have gone over several times and the relay I have clicks on time. When it clicks, the solenoid claps on command but not fully. The solenoid is typically powered by a 9 volt battery. I am somehow dropping volts along my circuit and I do not know how. If I take the wires connected to the relay and just touch them together, the clapper solenoid claps on queue with 0 problem. But WITH the relay, it is lackluster.

What gives me pause is I have a second solenoid that is also powered by a 9 volt battery. When I attach that one to the circuit, it claps fully without issue.

So because of the touching wires manually, I assume my circuit is fine. I have checked it when it's connected to the relay though and it seems to only be getting maybe 4.5 volts. Still, it's enough to charge 1 solenoid but not the one I need.

Is the relay the reason for the dropped volts? Or do I really need to go over the wiring meticulously even though it fires manually. I've checked my power supply and it's giving off 12 volts consistently.

Any advice is appreciated.

You can see an old post of a similar issue I had here [Solenoid circuit not firing](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/550196/solenoid-circuit-not-firing)

Comment: Which relay module that is? How much current the solenoid requires? How much current the supply can provide?

Comment: It is similar to https://www.amazon.com/AEDIKO-8-Channel-Relay-Module/dp/B0B9X675NQ

I based my project on this instructable https://www.instructables.com/A-Raspberry-Pi-Powered-Junk-Drum-Machine/

He is using a 12 volt 10 amp, I am using 12 volt 2 amp AC adapter. I do not know how much current the solenoid requires, just that it typically uses a 9 volt battery which is usually 1.5 amps right? So I figured 12 volt 2 amps was enough

Comment: It is an 8 channel 5 volt relay. Does it keep the voltage under 5 volts then? I am just realizing that's 100 percent what it could be. I assume I need to buy a higher voltage relay?

Comment: The 5V relay means the coil. Not the contacts. 100% not the problem. If you don't know how much the solenoid requires current at 12V, you don't know if a 12V 2A supply is enough.

Comment: Okay. The reason I assume the 12v 2amp supply is enough is it fires without the relay being involved when I just touch the wires that should be attached to the relay together. Also, since the solenoid is typically powered by a 9 volt battery, using anymore power would fry the solenoid if connected wouldn't it?

Comment: True. But then we don't know if one relay is broken. Did you try different relay channel? Did you use thick enough wire? Diode in proper orientation? Maybe the schematics are not wrong, but built with error, or incorrect wires or diodes? Which diodes and wires you used and how did you connect them? Show a photo to get an idea if it is built like the schematics.

Comment: I have tried different relay channels. I am using thick enough wire. The diode is in the orientation as given in the instructable. I have a 12 volt 10 amp power supply with me here and I might just plug it in to see if it will work for a second. Good idea????? lol

Comment: I'll see if I can add pictures in a bit.

Comment: measure all the voltages in the clapper circuit

Comment: So I ran my project slowly so the relay clicks only once every 4 seconds. When plugged in the clapper is regularly receiving 5 volts regardless of what else is happening. But when it clicks on/off (depending on how I wired it to the relay) it skips up to the full 12 volts. Why would it be receiving 5 volts even though the relay is off?

Comment: So I measured the wires that directly feed the clapper.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Thanks for pushing me to test all the wires again.

I hate to admit it but it was a combination of things. I didn't understand how the relay is meant to FULLY turn off and on. The program I am running for it (on/off library) gives you a lot of ways to start the process and for some reason my program is bugged and is being told to start ON when it should start OFF.

When I changed the program around and put it altogether, the solenoid fires correctly. Circuit was all good. Thank you guys